# Meteor How to call helper of a template into another template helper?

Tags: meteor

I have a search template where search is working fine. Now i need to call same search event in my navbar.js file. is it possible to call helper of other template in my navbar template helper.

templates\pages\search\search.js helper

```
Template.Search.events({

  "keyup #searchFormInput": _.throttle((e, tmpl) => {
    let text = $(e.target).val().trim();
    console.log(text);
    if (text.length)
      ArgSearch.search(text);
  }, 200)

});

Template.Search.helpers({
  'getResults' () {
    return ArgSearch.getData({});
  }
});
```

templates\shared\nav\navbar.js

trying to call it like

```
Template.Topnavright.events({

    Template.Topnavright.__helpers.get('Search')();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to create a shared context, that is updated and used by both templates:

*imports/somewhere/context.js*

```js
export const Shared = {
  ArgSearch: ArgSearch,
}
```

*templates\pages\search\search.js*

```js
import {Shared} from 'imports/somewhere/context.js'

Template.Search.events({

  "keyup #searchFormInput": _.throttle((e, tmpl) => {
    let text = $(e.target).val().trim();
    console.log(text);
    if (text.length)
      Shared.ArgSearch.search(text);
  }, 200)

});

Template.Search.helpers({
  'getResults' () {
    return Shared.ArgSearch.getData({});
  }
});
```

*templates\shared\nav\navbar.js*

```js
import {Shared} from 'imports/somewhere/context.js'

Template.Topnavright.events({
  someHelpers () {
    return Shared.ArgSearch.getData({});
  }
});
```

Note, that you can also share `ReactiveVar` or `ReactiveDict` instances with a shared context, which acts a bit like `Session` but in a limited scope.

Comment: But i have single search input type in topbar and on keypress of it i want to call search template. so that all records will come there when user will type any keyword in serch input type. This topbar is coming on all pages.

Comment: You don't "call" the search template but alter the data source on which the search Template "listens" to. This is a standard approach in model-view-controller designs and should work for your setup well.

Comment: Is there any example or any reference?

Comment: This is one possible approach to solve the issue you described, so you won't find it in the docs. The appraoch assumes, that your `ArgSearch` is somehow global but still limited to certain components. Therefore it makes sense to share it as a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) via module export and keep your code maintainable. Did this answer solve your problem?